# How to use one proxy address in browser to communication with multiple docker containers

Tags: networking, proxy, docker, squid

I create one image which include vpn client and squid as proxy service. Due to restricted for the VPN client,multiple vpn client can't connect different datacenter(customers) at the same time within in one container.
that why I up three container in this case. 
0.0.0.0:32768->3128/tcp DCA

0.0.0.0:32769->3128/tcp DCB

0.0.0.0:32770->3128/tcp DCC

No issue for ssh now. however to browser the web page (name standard is dca.abc.host.com) from DCA or others. I need setup proxy in chrome/firefox like (my ip address:32768). but I got more than 5-7 different DC customers need to switch every time.

Is that any solution only one proxy set up in firefox let me browser the page among different vpn.

Comment: A single proxy server can do this, if you configure it properly. There's no need for three of them.

Comment: Can you give me some sample or key word for the set up ? thanks